# Detect the direction change on hammer.js event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, hammer.js

I'm dragging an element using `hammer.js` and I'm looking for a way to distinguish in which way the rage going.

On general i'm using

```
evt.gesture.deltaX>0 //right
evt.gesture.deltaX<0 //left
```

But the `deltaX` is referring to the drag starting, so When I'm changing way during the dragging, I don't know it.

any way to get the direction change immediately?

Comment: Wondering whether the answer helped...

Answer (score 2):

You can determine the correct direction during dragging by passing the center value of last event and current event to the `Hammer.utils.getDirection()` utility method as shown below:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('sandbox');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var lastCenter;

function onDrag(ev){
    var center = ev.gesture.center;
    if (lastCenter)
        /* use the built in direction determination of hammer
       but use the last position instead of the starting position */
        output.innerHTML = Hammer.utils.getDirection(lastCenter, center);
    lastCenter = center;
}

function onRelease(){
    lastCenter = null;
}

var hammertime = Hammer(el);
hammertime.on("drag", onDrag);
hammertime.on("release", onRelease);
```

```css
#sandbox
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    line-height:150px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    background-color: #29A3CC;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/1.1.3/hammer.min.js"></script>
<div id="sandbox">Drag the mouse here</div> 
<div id="output"></div>
```

<sub>Note: this doesn't work with latest 2.x versions</sub>

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
evt.gesture.direction
```

possible values are left/right/up/down
check the demo here: http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/examples/events.html

Comment: The direction have the same problem, is show right even i started to drag left.
any other idea?

Comment: are you using touch event? if so there is no way we can know the direction. only after drag event can we know the direction. It may be better to listen to only dragleft and dragright event.

    var hammertime = Hammer(element).on("dragleft dragright", function(event) {
        alert('hello!');
    });

Comment: Didn't work out for me. have the same problem. the event changed only if i pass the original point. any other idea?

Comment: Could you post any screen-shots or illustration of what you want to do? It may help us give better answers.

Comment: Think about dragged ball, just want to catch when he change the direction. finally i did it with an extra var that save the old X, and then i calculated the deltaX.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is 7yo but has not yet been answered, now (`hammer 2.0.8`) there are different events you can listen to per direction. For example:

```
  private hammerManager: HammerManager | null = null;

  private onRefSet(node: HTMLDivElement | null) {
    if (!node || this.hammerManager) { return; }
    this.hammerManager = new Hammer(node);
    this.hammerManager.get('swipe').set({
      direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL,
    });
    this.hammerManager.on('swipeleft', e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
    this.hammerManager.on('swiperight', e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }
```

More info in the docs https://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-swipe/

(the example I wrote uses `"@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.40"`)